# How to find first occurrence of a significant difference in values of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In a **Pandas DataFrame**, how would I find the first occurrence of a large difference between two values at two adjacent indices?

As an example, if I have a **DataFrame** column *A* with data `[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 15, 15.1]`, I would want index holding 1.5, which would be 5. In my code below, it would give me the index holding 7.2, because `15 - 7.2 > 7 - 1.5`.

```
idx = df['A'].diff().idxmax() - 1
```

How should I fix this problem, so I get the index of the first 'large difference' occurrence?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#:~:text=argmax,-numpy.&text=Returns%20the%20indices%20of%20the%20maximum%20values%20along%20an%20axis.&text=Input%20array.&text=By%20default%2C%20the%20index%20is,otherwise%20along%20the%20specified%20axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is of course how you define a "large difference". Your solution is pretty good to get the largest difference, improved only by using `.diff(-1)` and using absolute values as shown by Jezrael:

```py
differences = df['A'].diff(-1).abs()
```

Using absolute values matters if your values are not sorted, in which case you can get negative differences.

Then, you should probably do some clustering on these values and get the smallest index of the cluster with largest values. Jezrael already showed a heuristic by using the largest quartile, however by only slightly modifying your example this doesn’t work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1.05, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 15, 15.1]})
differences = df['A'].diff(-1).abs()
idx = differences.index[differences >= differences.quantile(.75)][0]
print(idx, differences[idx])
```

This returns `1 0.1499999999999999`

Here's 3 other heuristics that might work better for you:

- If you have a value above which you consider a difference to be “large” (e.g. `1.5`):

  ```py
  idx = differences.index[differences >= 1.5][0]
  ```
- If you know how many large values there are, you can select those and get the smallest index (e.g. `2`):

  ```py
  idx = differences.nlargest(2).index.min()
  ```
- If you know all small values are grouped together (as are all the 0.1 in your example), you can filter what's larger than the mean (or the mean + 1 standard deviation if your “large” values are very close to the smaller ones).

  ```py
  idx = differences.index[differences >= differences.mean()][0]
  ```

  This is because contrarily to the median, your few large differences will pull the mean up significantly.

If you really want to go for proper clustering, you can use the KMeans algorithm from scikit learn:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(differences.values[:-1].reshape(-1, 1))
clusters = pd.Series(kmeans.labels_, index=differences.index[:-1])
idx = clusters.index[clusters.eq(np.squeeze(kmeans.cluster_centers_).argmax())][0]
```

This classifies the data into 2 classes, and then gets the classification into a pandas Series. We then filter this series’ index by selecting only the cluster that has the highest values, and finally get the first element of this filtered index.

Comment: I'm finding that adding 3 standard deviations to the mean is working for my sample case. Which kinda makes sense if there are few large gaps, and we assume a fairly normal distribution.

Comment: Also I like your idea of clustering. It's funny because I'm trying to find the "first large" eigengap for use in k-estimation for spectral clustering.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is filter by [`Series.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) with Series of differences with change order of differencies by `-1` and aboslute values, last get first index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 15, 15.1]})


x = df['A'].diff(-1) .abs()
print (x)
0     0.1
1     0.1
2     0.1
3     0.1
4     0.1
5     5.5
6     0.1
7     0.1
8     7.8
9     0.1
10    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64

idx = x.index[x >= x.quantile(.75)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([5, 7, 8], dtype='int64')

print (idx[0])
5
```

Comment: Would the .abs() affect the function if the data had negative values?

Comment: @BobTomato - hmm, here is used `abs` after difference, reason is compare by `quantile` only positive differencies. So not easy answering by `Would the .abs() affect the function if the data had negative values?`, because it depends by output of `diff` method.

Comment: @BobTomato abs is important of your values are not sorted, but the sign of the values themselves does not matter.

Comment: @jezrael I see...I've tried playing around with the quantiles and it outputs different results based on the data so it can't really generalize.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Numpy Array, which you can use any dataframe row as, you can use `numpy.argmax`.

```py
import numpy as np

import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 15, 15.1])
diff = np.diff(a)
threshold = 2 # set your threshold
max_index = np.argwhere(diff> threshold) [[5],[8]]
```

References:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html

More Info:

`pandas.diff` will calculate the diff `diff[i] = a[i] - a[i-1]`
`numpy.diff` will calculate the diff `diff[i] = a[i+1] - a[i]`,
with the exception of i=max len:

- a[i] = a[i]-a[i-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
def shift(a):
  
  a_r = np.roll(a, 1) # right shift
  a_l = np.roll(a, -1) # left shift


  return np.stack([a_l, a_r], axis=1)
```

---

```
a = np.array([1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 15, 15.1])
```

---

```
diff = abs(shift(a) - a.reshape(-1, 1))

diff = diff[1:-1]

indices = diff.argmax(axis=0) - 2

a[indices]
```

---

```
array([7. , 1.5])
```